# rsyslog: How do I direct messages from all remote machines to one file?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

We have a syslog server and we have all our servers logging to it.

We want a sort of "catch-all" drippan rule for all remote messages that we have not configured a rule for.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is how I configured this in `rsyslog.conf`:

```
# Log remote hosts to separate log file
$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/remote-hosts/%HOSTNAME%.log"
$template RemoteHostFileFormat,"%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogfacility-text% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::space-cc,drop-last-lf%\n"
:inputname, isequal, "imudp" ?PerHostLog;RemoteHostFileFormat
& ~
```

This traps all log messages received via UDP (`imudp`) and puts it in a file whose filename corresponds to the hostname the log message originated from.

Comment: Thank you for the example using inputname. Half a dozen examples I found all tried matching on $hostname and the like... and none of them worked reliably for this :)

Comment: HI, this works, expcept the 'last message repeated x times' messages end up in /var/log/remote-hosts/.log.

Answer (score 0):

I found very nice "how to" that will give you a good head start...

[How to Setup Rsyslog Remote Logging on Linux (Central Log Server)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/rsyslog-remote-logging/)

Comment: Edited question to clarify what I want. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: my answer will do exactly that

Comment: I believe the submitter is looking for a rule to use on the _receiving_ syslog server to dump messages into files.

Comment: That's correct. My apologies @alexus for not being clear initially.

Comment: Pretty sparse on that link.